# Alphashape produces unexpected multipolygons for big point clouds

Tags: python, 2d, alpha-shape

I'm using:

- Alpha Shape Toolbox version 1.3.1;
- Python version 3.10.9;
- Operating System Windows 10.

While making an `alphashape` for a group of 2D points, unexpected results with a `MultiPolygon` are obtained. I expected in each case a single `Polygon`.

[Example 1: 2 polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhILr.jpg)    [Example 2: many polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xx0rG.jpg)   [Example 2: many polygons (zoomed in)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvx6c.jpg)
(Points are grey, single polygons of the extracted `MultiPolygon` each have a different color)

Unfortunately I cannot include the list of points as it's way too long (885 points for example 1 and 1.5 mio for example 2)

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a limit of pointcount, that `alphashape` can handle?

```
import alphashape
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = np.loadtxt('points_for_alphashape.txt')
shape = alphashape.alphashape(points, alpha=0.5)
print(type(shape))
plt.scatter(*zip(*points), c='gray', s=0.1)
for shape in shape.geoms:
    x,y = shape.exterior.xy
    plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I had the same problem. I managed to get an instance of `Polygon` by adjusting the value of `alpha`.